# Separating words in a sentence

Tags: comprehension

I am teaching myself Japanese with the aid of beginners textbooks and internet resources. I have learnt to read both the hiragana and katakana alphabets (yay!) I felt super excited and started trying to read everything I could... I bought little manga books intended for *very* young children, and thought I could just use translators to translate what I was now reading. However, not knowing where words start or end I cannot differentiate actual sentences from just a jumble of sounds :-(

What should I do to understand what I'm reading?

Comment: Ifyouknowthewords,youcanseparatesentenceswithoutspaceseasily.Itjustrequiressomepractice. See also: [resources-for-learning-japanese](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/) You could also start with [Tae Kim's tutorial](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/complete).

Comment: Also, if you're into Pokemon games, setting the language to Japanese uses all *kana* with spaces between words.

Comment: Rather than learning materials, [Morphological analysers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese/773#773) will help the asker. Mecab does nice job: it can parse "それはなかなかいいかんがえですね" into "それ/は/なかなか/いい/かんがえ/です/ね".

Answer (score 1):

If you work through a textbook, the vocabulary you need should be built up from the ground. Once you know some sentence structure, this should be enough to figure out word boundaries in elementary picture books, which allows you to look up words in any dictionary.

Some books for pre-school children actually do put spaces between words for better readability, so could start with that. (For example, you may know [すてきな 三にんぐみ](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%81%99%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E4%B8%89%E3%81%AB%E3%82%93%E3%81%90%E3%81%BF-%E3%83%88%E3%83%9F%E3%83%BC-%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B2%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC/dp/4033270205/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1425986080&sr=8-1&keywords=%E3%81%99%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E4%B8%89%E3%81%AB%E3%82%93%E3%81%90%E3%81%BF), which has spaces and is translated using only katakana & hiragana.)

Generally, I think it's a great idea to try to read children's books, but be aware that these are intended for children who are already fluent in spoken Japanese. At times you may have trouble finding words, even if you know how they are spelled in kana (which is why I would suggest you start with a book you know well in your native language).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Earthliŋ's answer, particularly about looking for books with spaces between words, but I'd like to add a few more thoughts and point out some specific issues.

There are different levels books aimed for very young children.  First there are baby books, for children who are just learning words.  These will usually just have one or two words with each picture, e.g., かー　and/or ぶーぶー.  The first is just the word for car, and the second is the sound it makes.  In general, Japanese children's books use a lot of onomatopoeia, most of which can be found in dictionaries, but in simple cases you can guess the meaning from context.  These should not be too hard to read.

However, baby books are probably not super interesting.  A big issue when reading simple story books, in addition to a lot of vocabulary you wouldn't learn in introductory textbooks, is the use of slang and things like word play.  First, most (but not all) introductions to Japanese start off by teaching you polite Japanese, which is not how kids learn (familiar, casual Japanese).  So kids books will use a lot of casual Japanese.  Second, there's a lot of slang in spoken Japanese, just like in English, and this will appear in kids books as well.
(e.g., しています meaning "is doing" is している in normal casual Japanese, but often pronounced and written as してる.)

As for finding gaps between words, even as you progress it takes effort.  One thing you could do is use a good online dictionary (or tools like rikai-chan), preferably one that will recognize verb conjugations, as you will run into a lot of conjugated verbs you need to work to try out various possibilities to find the root of  (I think jisho.org, at least the beta version, may do this for you.)  This helps, but you may still need to try several possibilities to figure out what the words are.  It is also much easier to determine where words begin and end when you have a good sense of the grammar, which you'll need to make sense of what the words mean when strung together.

Anyway, I think reading children's books is great, but assuming you mean simple story books, you may either want to wait until you learn a decent amount of grammar (e.g., maybe after going through 1-2 introductory books) or start with bilingual children's books.  There are a lot of these available in Japan (though I don't know if they'll be easy for you to get) aimed at teaching Japanese kids English from a young age.

I probably didn't start reading children's books until covering roughly 1-2 semesters of Japanese, and even then learning to read children's books was a very slow process for me (mainly due to vocab, grammar and slang), so you need to be patient.  Treat it like a research project.  Invariably, there will be times when you get stuck, and then you can ask someone you know or ask on here for specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Tae Kim](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar), read up to Advanced section, stop. His format is flawed and he doesn't explain a lot of things that he should and tailors his stuff mostly to speaking as opposed to reading but it's totally fine as a start. A universal screwdriver, of sorts.

Then:

[http://www.amazon.com/A-Dictionary-Basic-Japanese-Grammar/dp/4789004546](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/4789004546) + Intermediate / Advanced variants.

Get these three, they'll cover a lot of things Tae Kim didn't. Keep reading and re-reading them, writing out sentences for practice etc.

**MOST IMPORTANTLY, HAVE FUN** Find something you'd LOVE to read/watch (books, Yotsuba, TV drama, tentacle pron whatever) to motivate you, doesn't matter how advanced - the point is to motivate you and if you like it enough you'll persevere with it anyway. VNs (visual novels) are the perfect learning method IMO (assuming you can handle the occasional icky bits) as you can parse their text into text editors and rip voice audio to Anki to grind your listening skills.

Grow your anki deck.

Don't overestimate the difficulty of learning. It's a language learnable by kids and people with far, far below average intellect (as for the argument that kids learn languages easier, I myself find learning languages a lot easier in my late 20s compared to my younger self). Harder than learning another European language for a European, yes, but not nearly as hard as, say, becoming proficient at a sport or a musical instrument.

Have fun!

Comment: thank you everyone for indulging my beginner's query and all the kind help. 
It's very daunting right now and I got over excited at learning the alphabets, then not really being able to utilise my new skill due to translation obstacles. 
(thanks to Earthlin for editing the comments, appreciated)